# How to send a notification from an android app to another android device using phone number?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, notifications

I am developing an android application and i need to send a notification from the app to a phone number (another device).

Can anyone tell me how can i implement this? any methods or API i can use?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do it without developing server-side software that Android devices will connect to. In your server-side software you can use [FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/) or any other framework/library to send notifications to one or group of devices.

Problem is that you need to have connection to the other device and you can't know if that device is connected to internet and even if it is you don't know the address of that device. 99.99% that you need server-side software.

Comment: i have all information about the device which i am gonna use it phone number (the location, the user information) and i am sure it will be connected to the internet, i was hoping there is a way to do it using only phone number. thanks for you response

Comment: Notifications are sent over internet, usually over HTTP. To properly send HTTP requests and responses, or any other protocol over TCP, sender needs to know receivers IP and port and vice versa because they need to form connection before sending packages. Phone number is useless here.I would recommend you to learn more about computer networks and protocols and that will help you understand how things works and will make you better developer in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way (but the most expensive i guess) is to have the first device send a request to a server (whose backend you have to build, eg. php) that will send a push notification to the second device via Google Cloud messaging service.

that's not so easy because the second device to receive the notification must register at GCM and the first device must identificate the id of this device (the common way is to have a common id like username)

Answer (score 0):

There is on possibility without using server side code, Send SMS to the second  Phone and read the SMS in second phone and display your notification in second phone. It will cost the SMS charges in both phones.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i don't think my client will like this method

Comment: what type of notification do you want to send?

Comment: Is there a way to send an SMS for free?

Answer (score 0):

Create an API that communicates with the users of the application this will be able to send updates to the registered users at real-time.
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/